# Datatable buttons not showing in Laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatables

I have a problem loading the export buttons on DataTable, is my script not in order? I don't have any errors on console. Please help me.

Script for DataTable

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/datetime/1.0.3/js/dataTables.dateTime.min.js"></script>




<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

   **DataTable Filter**

var minDate, maxDate;
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
        var min = $("#min").val();
        var max = $("#max").val();
        var date =  data[1] ;
        //return(data[1] == "2021-05-18")
        if (
           ( min === null && max === null ) ||
           ( min === null && date <= max ) ||
           ( min <= date   && max === null ) ||
            ( min <= date   && date <= max )
       ) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
);

   **Initialize Datatable for export buttons**

  var table = $("#admintable").DataTable({
  dom: 'Bfrtip',
  buttons: [
            'copyHtml5',
            'excelHtml5',
            'csvHtml5',
            'pdfHtml5'
        ]

});
     
$('.generate').click(function(){
    table.draw();

});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Yeah, it's closed now, but still buttons are not showing

Comment: where is your datatable initialising javascript ? and your table tag too ??

Comment: is datatable visible ??

Comment: Yes it's visible

Comment: remove included js https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js and reload and check

Comment: still buttons not showing,

Comment: To help make it easier to troubleshoot this, you can provide a [mre]. When I use the code in the question, the buttons are displayed correctly.

Comment: when I refresh it 3 or more times, it displayed. Weird